# Reference .NETCoreApp NuGet from NET47 WPF App

Tags: wpf, .net-core, .net-standard

Is it possible to reference a .NETCoreApp 2.0 built NuGet package within a WPF App on Framework 4.7

I have built my own NuGet but fails to add the package:

Could not install package 'My.Common 1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The package dependencies:

[image: Package dependencies]

Do we have to wait until NETStandard 2.0? It's fine I can cross compile using;

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Although I'd rather target less frameworks!

Comment: If you don't use preview tooling you also can't (or shouldn't) build for `netcoreapp2.0`

Comment: Tried using Visual Studio 15.3 preview but doesn't seem to work well with cross compiling both NET47 & NETStandard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `netcoreapp` is always framework that is incompatible to `net`. .NET Core can (and does) implement APIs that aren't available on .NET Framework.

With "current" (.NET CLI < 2.0, VS 2017 < 15.3) tooling, the highest version of .NET Standard that .NET 4.7 can use is `netstandard15` (which can be used on .NET Framework 4.6.2).

Even when .NET Standard 2.0 (tooling) is released, .NET Framework projects cannot reference .NET Core libraries. Only higher .NET Standard versions.